# IIS and the number of w3wp processes

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008, asmx

I'm running IIS 7 on Server 2008, with a single AppPool for an application which is basically just a collection of ASP.NET WebMethods.  Some of these methods process for hours before they return.

What's weird, is that sometimes when I launch multiple simultaneous requests IIS spins up a single w3wp process (and seems to share it amongst the requests) and other times it spins up multiple w3wp processes (1 for each request).

I am always careful to use task mgr and view processes for all users when observing this.  Can anyone explain this inconsistent behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default each app pool gets 1 w3wp process, but in a web garden multiple w3wp processes can exist per app pool.

**Edit:** A little more info about [web gardens](http://blogs.iis.net/chrisad/archive/2006/07/14/1342059.aspx)

Comment: Do you know how the web garden decides whether to kick off a new w3wp process for a request, or whether to share a single w3wp process for multiple requests?

Comment: I am not sure when another process kicks off, but you can control the maximum number of processes in iis. In IIS6 Just find the app pool right click, properties, and you will see maximum worker processes (in ii7 it is under advanced settings  of the app pool).

Answer (score 0):

It may be time to re-think your web-garden.  Scott Forsyth has an interesting 11 minute vLog on why webgardens are counterproductive: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/iis/Why-You-Shouldnt-Use-Web-Gardens-in-IIS-Week-24.aspx

Links to articles he mentions in his VLog:

Tuning recommendations for IIS6 and IIS7 -- read the whole article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268 
Further information http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx

His bottom line is if you have performance problems that are resolved by web gardens—use the web gardens as a great crutch until the underlying performance issue (usually resource contention) is resolved.